# Возникла проблема при создании крестиков-ноликов на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

При создании игры "крестики-нолики" для одного игрока возникла проблема и она заключается в следующем.
При нажатии пользователем на ячейку должен отображаться знак "X", но этого не происходит.
Хотел бы узнать, где находится этот недочет или ошибка и как ее можно исправить. В консоли ошибок нет.

P.S. В HTML создается главный элемент `<div>` с `id='mainBlock'`, а далее в нем создаются 9 `<div>` (через JS).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  document.getElementById('mainBlock').innerHTML += '<div class="block" onclick="rectangleSquare(' + i + ')"></div>';
}

var Player = prompt('Введите ваше имя', 'Player');
var allElementsInMainBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
console.log(allElementsInMainBlock);
var writeO;
/*onclick*/
function rectangleSquare(value) {
  if (allElementsInMainBlock[value] == 0) {
    allElementsInMainBlock[value] = 1;
    writeX(value);
    if (checkWinner() == true) {
      alert('Ты выиграл! Поздравляю!');
    } else {
      checkNobody();
      computerSolution();
      checkNobody();
    }
  }
}
/*написание 'X' в нужной ячейке */
function writeX(value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (value == i) {
      allElementsInMainBlock[value].innerHTML = 'X';
    }
  }
}

/*проверка на победу*/
function checkWinner() {
  if ((allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[1] && allElementsInMainBlock[1] == allElementsInMainBlock[2] && allElementsInMainBlock[2] > 0) ||
    (allElementsInMainBlock[3] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[5] && allElementsInMainBlock[5] > 0) ||
    (allElementsInMainBlock[6] == allElementsInMainBlock[7] && allElementsInMainBlock[7] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[8] > 0) ||
    (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[3] && allElementsInMainBlock[3] == allElementsInMainBlock[6] && allElementsInMainBlock[6] > 0) ||
    (allElementsInMainBlock[1] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[7] && allElementsInMainBlock[7] > 0) ||
    (allElementsInMainBlock[2] == allElementsInMainBlock[5] && allElementsInMainBlock[5] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[8] > 0) ||
    (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[8] > 0) ||
    (allElementsInMainBlock[2] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[6] && allElementsInMainBlock[6] > 0)) {
    return true;
  }
}

/*проверка на ничью*/
function checkNobody() {
  checkForADraw = false;
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[i] == 0) {
      checkForADraw = true;
    }
  }
  if (checkForADraw == false) {
    alert('Ничья');
  }
}

/*ход компьютера*/
function computerSolution() {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[i] == 0) {
      writeO = i;
    }
  }
  /*цикл защиты и победы компьютером*/
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    /*1-ая строка*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[1] == allElementsInMainBlock[2] && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[1] == i) {
      writeO = 0;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[2] && allElementsInMainBlock[1] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == i) {
      writeO = 1;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[1] && allElementsInMainBlock[2] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == i) {
      writeO = 2;
    }
    /*2-ая строка*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[5] && allElementsInMainBlock[3] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == i) {
      writeO = 3;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[3] == allElementsInMainBlock[5] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[3] == i) {
      writeO = 4;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[3] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[5] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[3] == i) {
      writeO = 5;
    }
    /*3-ья строка*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[7] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[6] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[7] == i) {
      writeO = 6;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[6] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[7] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[6] == i) {
      writeO = 7;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[6] == allElementsInMainBlock[7] && allElementsInMainBlock[8] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[6] == i) {
      writeO = 8;
    }

    /*1-ый столбец*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[3] == allElementsInMainBlock[6] && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[3] == i) {
      writeO = 0;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[6] && allElementsInMainBlock[3] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == i) {
      writeO = 3;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[3] && allElementsInMainBlock[6] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == i) {
      writeO = 6;
    }
    /*2-ой столбец*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[7] && allElementsInMainBlock[1] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == i) {
      writeO = 1;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[1] == allElementsInMainBlock[7] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[1] == i) {
      writeO = 4;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[1] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[7] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[1] == i) {
      writeO = 7;
    }
    /*3-ий столбец*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[5] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[2] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[5] == i) {
      writeO = 2;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[2] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[5] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[2] == i) {
      writeO = 5;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[2] == allElementsInMainBlock[5] && allElementsInMainBlock[8] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[2] == i) {
      writeO = 8;
    }

    /*1-ая диагональ*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == i) {
      writeO = 0;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[8] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == i) {
      writeO = 4;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[0] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[8] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[0] == i) {
      writeO = 8;
    }

    /*2-ая диагональ*/
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[4] == allElementsInMainBlock[6] && allElementsInMainBlock[2] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == i) {
      writeO = 2;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[2] == allElementsInMainBlock[6] && allElementsInMainBlock[4] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[2] == i) {
      writeO = 4;
    }
    if (allElementsInMainBlock[2] == allElementsInMainBlock[4] && allElementsInMainBlock[6] == 0 && allElementsInMainBlock[2] == i) {
      writeO = 6;
    }

    computerWrite(writeO);
    allElementsInMainBlock[writeO] = 2;
    if (checkWinner() == true) {
      alert('Победил компьютер!');
    }
  }
}
/*запись 'O' в нужную ячейку*/
function computerWrite(value) {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (value == i) {
      allElementsInMainBlock[value].innerHTML = 'O';
    }
  }
}
```